# emacs php completion

Tags: php, emacs

I've installed the php-mode for emacs, and I want the completion (ESC-TAB) to work for functions defined in the language. I've downloaded the manual in different html pages and run the following to generate the completion file:

```
cd /sviluppo/php-manual-xhtml
ls -1 function*.html | sed -e 's/^function\.\([-a-zA-Z_0-9]*\)\.html/\1/' | tr - _  > /sviluppo/emacs-lisp/php-completion-file
```

and in my .emacs file I placed the following instructions

```
(setq php-mmanual-path "/sviluppo/php-manual-xhtml")
(setq php-completion-file "/sviluppo/emacs-lisp/php-completion-file")
```

However the auto completion does not work: when I write for instance *iss* and hit ESC+TAB the minibuffer replies with

```
 No tags table loaded
```

but I don't want to use a tag table, I just want to see the possible functions. What am I missing here?

Comment: emacswiki has a completion backend for company: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CompanyModeBackends#PhpCompletion

Comment: @Tom what is the command to use company completion ?

Comment: @fluca1978 Are you able to use it ?